# How to remove transparent Toolbar padding when collapsed in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I use CollapsingToolbarLayout in my app but when it was collapsed, there is a marginLeft and marginRight in toolbar like picture below.
When I set the toolbar background not transparent ,such as red,it look as normal.
So how should I remove the margin？
[image: wrong toolbar with margin]

I want it be this below but background to be transparent

[image]
my xml code is

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/transparent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/transparent"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedText"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutCollapsedText"
        app:expandedTitleMarginTop="0dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/venueImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_height"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding `app:elevation="0dp"` to the `AppBarLayout` widget fixed this for me.

Also in my layout I have `AppBarLayout` nested inside `CoordinatorLayout` whereas your's is the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set `android:stateListAnimator` null in your `AppBarLayout`; something like

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"> // This works
```